# Applying AND condition on one field grails domain

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

In Grails, I have two domain classes having many to many relationship

```
class VisitingUser
{
  String name
  static hasMany = [visitedCountries:VisitedCountry]
  static belongsTo = VisitedCountry
}

class VisitedCountry
{
  String countryName
  static hasmany=[users:VisitingUser]
}
```

I want all those users who visited country "india" AND "usa" both.

Currently I am solving this problem by getting two list of visitingUsers, one for "india" and other for "usa" and then putting them in a Set.

I want a solution with using createCriteria or dynamic finder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible with a criteria query, and it's definitely not possible with a dynamic finder. Here's a solution with HQL though:

```
VisitingUser.executeQuery('''
select distinct u from VisitingUser u where
u in (
   select u from VisitingUser u join u.visitedCountries country where country.countryName = 'usa'
)
and u in (
   select u from VisitingUser u join u.visitedCountries country where country.countryName = 'india'
)
''')
```

Two unrelated things - `VisitedCountries` should be called `VisitedCountry` (although the set name `visitedCountries` makes sense because it will potentially have multiple elements), and the relationship should be many-to-many.

Comment: Thanks for solution and also for updating information about many to many.I have less idea about hql so I have two more query.(1)Can execute this hql command while using mongodb also? (2)Currently I followed grails docs for creating many to many relationship http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#manyToMany  , can I remove all hasmany and belongs to and create a third domain in grails having objects of VisitingUser and VisitedCountry Which one is better?

Comment: This won't work in MongoDB, only Hibernate since it gets translated to SQL. To map the join table, it's easiest to borrow code from the Spring Security plugin. Install spring-security-core (in a test app if you don't plan on using it) and run the s2-quickstart script. The generated UserRole class is what you want - change the class and field names to your classes. See http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=1992 for some notes about many-to-many in MongoDB.